# While comment autocomplete with using username is not working

Tags: support, comment-replies, autocomplete

I tried to comment on a question and point an user using @username but autocomplete is not working

May I know why it is happening?

I am using Google Chrome

Comment: You need to type at least one letter first in order for the auto complete popup to appear. Also note it's not enabled in the mobile theme.

Comment: @user34556 this type of user

Comment: [working just fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k2ISb.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment auto-complete will not work if the person you are referring is the owner of the post, because the owner of the post will be notified anyways, so its unnecessary there.

Note:-(As mentioned by Shadow Wizard)If there are multiple users commenting on the same post, then it will work, so as to properly refer whom the notification be sent.

Comment: If there is another user who posted a comment and the post owner also commented then it will work though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard you are right updating the answer